# Using Nokogiri to list which tags are present in the HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri to count out all of the attributes on an HTML page. Suppose I search Google, how could I count each HTML tag present from that domains source, using Nokogiri?

This is my starting point, that is not yielding the results I expect:

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"))
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(doc)
@doc.xpath("//*")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this will do what you're looking for:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'awesome_print'

# Create a Nokogiri document
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.stackoverflow.com/").read)
# Iterate each node in the result set, and for each tag, increment the appropriate counter on the output hash
ap doc.xpath("//*").map(&:name).each_with_object({}) {|n, r| r[n] = (r[n] || 0) + 1 }
```

And results:

```
{
        "html" => 1,
        "head" => 1,
       "title" => 1,
        "link" => 5,
        "meta" => 7,
      "script" => 13,
        "body" => 1,
    "noscript" => 2,
         "div" => 1429,
          "h3" => 99,
           "a" => 717,
          "ul" => 5,
          "li" => 89,
        "span" => 490,
        "form" => 1,
       "input" => 1,
          "br" => 4,
           "b" => 3,
          "ol" => 8,
          "h1" => 1,
         "img" => 9,
          "h2" => 1,
          "h4" => 1,
       "table" => 1,
          "tr" => 2,
          "th" => 5,
          "td" => 7
}
```

`#name` is the attribute on each node that has the tag's name, so we just reduce the node set into an output hash keyed off of that.